# The plugin does not save data

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm trying to make the plugin save data, but I'm getting this error and I do not know why.

The code:

```
function ippluginmenu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'ip configuración',
        'ip',
        'administrator',
        'ip-configuracion',
        'pagopcionesplugin',
        'dashicons-admin-generic'   // Icono del menú
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'ippluginmenu');

function pagopcionesplugin() {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>Parámetros de configuración</h1>
            <form methop="POST" action="options.php">

                <?php settings_fields('ip-settings'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections('ip-settings-import'); ?>
                <?php submit_button(); ?>

            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
}

function xmlurlcallback() {
    ?><input type="text" name="xml-url" id="xml-url" value="<?php echo get_option('xml-url'); ?>" /><?php 
}

function maxpropcallback() {
    ?><input type="text" name="max-prop" id="max-prop" value="<?php echo get_option('max-prop'); ?>" /><?php 
}

function displayheaderoptionscontent(){
    //to do
}

function ip_save_settings() {
    add_settings_section(
        "ip-settings",
        "Opciones de importación",
        "displayheaderoptionscontent",
        "ip-settings-import"
    );

    add_settings_field(
        "xml-url",
        "URL del archivo XML",
        "xmlurlcallback",
        "ip-settings-import",
        "ip-settings"
    );
    add_settings_field(
        "max-prop",
        "Máximo de propiedades imprtadas",
        "maxpropcallback",
        "ip-settings-import",
        "ip-settings"
    );

    register_setting(
        "ip-settings",
        "xml-url"
    );
    register_setting(
        "ip-settings",
        "max-prop"
    );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'ip_save_settings');
```

Don't save data.
The error:

[image]

Obviusly, the archive options.php exists in the file

Comment: So I noticed that the browser was sending the form via the `GET` method and *not* the supposedly `POST` method - and that's because of this typo: 'methop' as in `<form methop="POST"` - it's `method` and not 'methop'. Btw, just ignore my previous comment.